# Inequality with sums and products

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let a,b,c,d positive real numbers such that
$a+b<c+d$ and
$(a+b)(c+d)<ab+cd$.
Prove that
$(a+b)cd>(c+d)ab$

Source: book on olympiads
I tried manipulating the given statements and i obtained
$3ab<cd$
To use this i would need to show that $cd<3(a+b)$ but i am stuck.

Comment: How have you got $$3ab<cd$$?

Comment: $a+b<c+d<\frac{ab+cd}{a+b}$ so $4ab \leq (a+b)^2<ab+cd$   And then i got $a+b< \frac{c+d}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

Since $ab+cd>(a+b)(c+d)$ and $ab<a(a+b)<a(c+d)$, $cd>b(c+d)$. Thus $(a+b)cd>acd>ab(c+d)$.